# Authorization in multiple layers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, mediatr

I am building an application/web API with ASP.NET Core and MediatR.

The authentication (Google account) is done in ASP.NET Core. The controllers make only thin layer that delegates all the work to MediatR and its request handlers.

Regarding authorization, currently, my approach is, I have most controllers decorated with [Authorize] attribute and also respective request handlers in MediatR's pipeline check (via a behavior) if the user was authenticated, so there is a duplicity.

My question is, would that be a bad practice to have all controllers allowing anonymous access and only check the authentication/authorization in the MediatR's pipeline?

I, for sure, need to keep it in the request handlers, since they are forming the actual application layer and I want it to be independent from the ASP.NET. Also only this layer is tested.

Comment: If your code is only ever called from controllers, why do you need to [Auth] anything in layers lower down (mediatr handlers for example)

Comment: My reasons for that:
1. I want to have my controllers as thin as possible
2. I want to keep possibility to take my application layer and use it in another infrastructure

Comment: There's an example of a pipeline you could use- https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/10/13/mediatr-pipeline-examples/

Comment: I am already using MediatR's pipeline. My question is if it's "necessary" to do it both on ASP.NET controllers and MediatR pipeline. Whether going all anonymous on controllers is considered a bad practice.

Comment: imo - authorization should be the concern of the controller; but you want to make the controllers 'thin' - and more importantly re-use the mediatr handlers in other infrastructure, so this is an entirely 'it depends' question

Answer (score 1):

I would leave authorization up to the controller but that's just an opinion.

If you plan on using the handlers in other projects that don't have built in authorization capability, then leave them in the handlers.

This is an "it depends" question as it depends on your specific scenario.